# How to retrieve a field value before its last change in db2?

Tags: sql, db2, data-retrieval

I have a table that contain `nationalcode, status, changestatusdate`.
I want to fetch last `status` and the second last `status` for each `nationalcode`, but I have a problem:

For some of `nationalcode, changestatusdate` has modified and get new value, but `status` didn't modify, so we can't use `changestatusdate` to show status modification.  For example we have this data:

```
[nationalcode]       [status]   [changestatusdate]
[123]                  [1]          [20150101]
[123]                  [2]          [20150301]
[123]                  [2]          [20150315]
[123]                  [3]          [20150601]
[123]                  [1]          [20151201]
[123]                  [5]          [20160101]
[123]                  [5]          [20160301]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Ttk.png)

We need last `status(5)` and second last `status(1)`....how can we retrieve these data?

Comment: What's your Db2 version & platform?

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following approach:

- Filter the data so there are no duplicate statuses in adjacent rows.
- Enumerate the rows to so that last status is "1", the next to the last "2", and so on.
- Use conditional aggregation.

In a query, this looks like:

```
select t.national_code,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) as last_status,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then status end) as last_status_but_one
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by national_code order changestatusdate desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(status) over (partition by national_code order by changestatusdate) as prev_status
            from t
           ) t
      where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
group by national_code;
```

Comment: THANKS, but i can't use lag function...what should i do?

Comment: If you can't use `LAG` you can use a normal window function: `MAX(status) OVER(PARTITION BY national_code ORDER BY changestatusdate ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)`

Comment: @sab . . . Why can't you use `lag()`?  DB2 has support it for a long, long time.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but it will get you the last and second to last `status` values for each `nationalcode`:

```sql
SELECT status
FROM (
  SELECT nationalcode, status, changestatusdate,
    ROW_NUMBER OVER(
      PARTITION BY nationalcode -- Group rows by nationalcode
      ORDER BY changestatusdate DESC -- Order by most recent
    ) AS RowNum
  FROM (
    SELECT nationalcode, status, changestatusdate, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY nationalcode, status -- Group rows by (nationalcode, status)
        ORDER BY changestatusdate DESC -- Order by most recent
      ) AS RowNum
    FROM mytable
  ) src
  WHERE RowNum = 1 -- Get most recent row
) src
WHERE RowNum <= 2 -- Get two most recent rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH MYTABLE (nationalcode, status, changestatusdate) AS
(
VALUES
  (123, 1, 20150101)
, (123, 2, 20150301)
, (123, 2, 20150315)
, (123, 3, 20150601)
, (123, 1, 20151201)
, (123, 5, 20160101)
, (123, 5, 20160301)
)
*/
SELECT DISTINCT nationalcode, status
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    T.nationalcode, T.status
  , SUM
  (
    CASE WHEN STATUS = COALESCE
    (
      MAX(status) OVER (PARTITION BY nationalcode ORDER BY changestatusdate DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    , STATUS
    ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  ) OVER (PARTITION BY nationalcode ORDER BY changestatusdate DESC) FLAG
  FROM MYTABLE T
)
WHERE FLAG < 2
;
```